# Is there a way to auto-create a file with dependencies in Java and auto-install them?

Tags: java, packaging

The idea of keeping all open source libraries in my repo doesn't sound to me as a good practice. Any ideas? 
I do know this can easily be done in Python using virtual environment, is there there such a way in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some build tools which can manage dependencies:

- maven (xml configuration)
- gradle (groovy configuration)
- apache ivy (xml configuration, used by ant)

Comment: More complete that my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think maintaining a maven project might be a proper solution.

In the pom.xml files you can stablish all the dependencies that your Java project needs. They will be automatically "installed" once you execute the "install" maven phase.

Please have a look at

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 1):

maven with xml configuration is well suited for this purpose.